# SD-Card failures on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

I'm writing this question for a friend of mine who has a problem whit his SD card.

He is on Windows 10 and he doesn't know which SD card it is, it doesn't have any brand on it.

- Until then, he was able to transfer a quantity of files correctly. While unplugging and replugging the SD card, they are still on it. This information is important.
- At a certain point, the copy doesn't work correctly anymore. When he transfers a folder in the card, it is actually paste. He can enter the folder, meaning it is on the SD card.
- However, when he unpluggs and repluggs the SD card, what the folder contained is gone. The folder is still there but everyting on it disappears.
- He already tried to reformat his card but it doesn't change anything.

He told me it's a 1To SD card and that's why he would be abashed throwing it.

Comment: Most likely the SD-card is a fake (hardware fraud), it claims to have 1TB but internally the flash chips have only 16, 32 or 128 GB. Use a fake flash test tool like [h2testw](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml) to test the SD-card if it can really hold 1TB.

Comment: Yes;  The behavior you describe absolutely is an indication the card isn't actually 1 TB.  Unless your friend can get a refund, it's trash, the amount of effort to get the device to display the real size isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you @Robert and Ramhound. You can post an answer so I can select it if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the SD-card is a fake (hardware fraud), it claims to have 1TB but internally the flash chips have only 16, 32 or 128 GB.

If you then write more data to it than the physical capacity the already written data gets overwritten or the data that is too large for the flash chips is simply ignored.

Use a fake flash test tool like [h2testw](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml) to test the SD-card if it can really hold 1TB. Some more Windows tools that can be used for identifying fake cards are listed [here](https://www.geckoandfly.com/22803/detect-fake-usb-flash-drives-sd-cards-ssd-disk/).

If the card is really a fake your friend should return the card and demand to get a refund. And the next time don't buy offers that are too cheap to be true...